# Identify the checksum algorithm

Tags: algorithm, checksum, 8051

I am trying to reverse-engineering a device (an 8 bit microcontroller) that comunicates with the PC. Each microcontroller has a Serial number of two digits (in decimal) that is used to calculated a checksum. For the same data message the checksum changes from device to device. Each message starts with an 0x02 and ends with a 0x03. The checksum is the number that appears between 0x04 and 0x03. These are the messages in Hexa and a translation to Ascii code:

```
02 41 42 42 04 31 30 03   .ABB.10.    //device ID :00
02 41 42 42 04 44 44 03    .ABB.DD.    //device ID : 01     
02 41 42 42 04 31 39 03    .ABB.19.    //device ID : 56  
02 41 42 42 04 35 34 03    .ABB.54.    //device ID : 99 


02 41 42 31 30 04 37 39 03  .AB10.79.   //device ID :00
02 41 42 31 30 04 34 45 03  .AB10.4E.   //device ID : 01
02 41 42 31 30 04 45 35 03  .AB10.E5.   //device ID : 56  
02 41 42 31 30 04 35 45 03  .AB10.5E.   //device ID : 99

02 41 42 70 04 41 43 03    .ABp.AC.    //device ID :00
02 41 42 70 04 36 31 03    .ABp.61.    //device ID : 01    
02 41 42 70 04 45 38 03    .ABp.E8.    //device ID : 56         
02 41 42 70 04 41 35 03     .ABp.A5.    //device ID : 99

02 41 42 30 46 46 46 46 04 46 30 03  .AB0FFFF.F0. //device ID:00
02 41 42 30 46 46 46 46 04 35 34 03  .AB0FFFF.54. //device ID : 01     
02 41 42 30 46 46 46 46 04 36 33 03  .AB0FFFF.63. //device ID : 56    
02 41 42 30 46 46 46 46 04 31 45 03  .AB0FFFF.1E. //device ID :99
```

I think that is making a kind of Xor but i cant figure how. Also as you can see , the checksum changes for different devices ID. I need to identify how the whole chekcsum is calculated with the data + device ID, or at least identify how the device ID is changing the checksum between different devices. The microcontroller is an 8 bit uc 8051. I will be very greatful  if someone can give me any clue on how it its working.

Updat: Now i can modify the  data of 1 message and see how the checksum varies according to the data that is given. Here is an example:

```
02 41 42 5a 43 30 30 38 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30   .ABZC00800000000 
30 04 37 35 03                                    0.75.
```

For the command ABZC008 i can modify the data that comes after de number eight. in this case the checksum is 75.

Here is another example where i put the data to 1s:

```
02 41 42 5a 43 30 30 38 30 31 31 31 31 31 31 31   .ABZC00801111111 
20 04 39 44 03                                     .9D.
```

Comment: Doesn't the vendor provide this information in a data sheet or user guide?

Comment: BTW: How do you know that this is the message format? How do the receiver know the ID of the transmitter? Without knowing the ID of the transmitter, it seems hard (impossible?) to verify a checksum that depends on an ID.

Comment: Hi, no the provider specifies that the ID consists of 2 numbers, from '00' to '99' decimal. Also when the first conecction happens, the device sends the ID to the PC , then send the messages that I posted above. I know the message format is 0x02+data+0x04+checksum+0x03,  i visualice the protocol on a Serial Port Viewer

Comment: 0x02, 0x03, and 0x04 are ASCII control characters, STX "Start of Text", ETX "End of Text", and EOT "End of Transmission", respectively.

Comment: Do you have access to the binary of the firmware? Since multiple CRC8 algorithms ring no bell, it might be easier to re-engineer the algorithm. It might well be something built from the "Not Invented Here(TM)" attitude.

Comment: i have access to the .hex file  that i dissasebmly using Ghidra, but i cant deduce how is it calculating the checksum .  I strongly belive is an Xor + other  unknow mathematical opperation , but as i say looking at the dissasembly code i cant figure out how is it calculating the checksum.  In the binary of the Uc i detected some  code that can possible be calculatin the checksum with Xors, but i cant conffirm that

Comment: Update: I found that only the first message that is a kind of "connection" message, doesn't deppend on the device ID. It's the same for all devices! : maybe it can give us any clue?  02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 41 42 20 3e 78 4e 60 46 46 46 46 04 36 39 03  .  In ASCCI :  ...........AB >x N`FFFF.69.   As you can see the checksum is 69 for all devices ! it makes sense that the first meesage doesnt include the device ID because it is not send from the Uc to the PC until the 2nd message. ¿Can you deduce anything from this message?